# 2D Grid of objects in p5.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, 2d, p5.js

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to create a Battleships game and at the moment I am working on drawing the board so that each spot is an object. So that when the user clicks on them, they can select where to place their battleships. I am trying to do this through storing each spot as an object in an array called circles.

[Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aflTa.png)

**The problem**

My problem is that when trying to create the objects, I can only seem to make the entire grid as one object. Here is the code I have so far (sorry for the quality, I am a noob!):

```
var circles = [];
var x = 100;
var y = 100;
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    circles[i] = {
        drawGrid: function() {
            for (var x = 100; x <= 1000; x += 100) {
                for (var y = 100; y <=1000; y += 100) {
                    fill(0);
                    ellipse(x,y,20,20);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1100,1100);
}

function draw() {
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        circles[i].drawGrid();
    }
}
```

I have tampered with the arrangement of the for loops (x, y and i) but nothing seems to work and if I try anything else, instead of getting a grid like the one below - with each O being an object:

```
O O O O 
O O O O
O O O O
O O O O
```

I will get something like one of these:

```
1) O O O O   | 2) O
   O         |      O
   O         |        O
   O         |          O
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would make a constructor function for the circle, like this:

```js
var circles = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  //there's a "b" for every "a"
  for (var a = 10; a < width; a += 30) {
    for (var b = 10; b < height; b += 30) {
      //add the circles to the array at x = a and y = b
      circles.push(new Circle(a, b));
    }
  }
  console.log(circles.length);

}

function draw() {
  background(50);
  for (var b = 0; b < circles.length; b++) {
    circles[b].show();
    //console.log("shown");
  }
}

function Circle(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  this.show = function() {
    fill(255);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
    //console.log("showing");
  }
}
```

of course you'll have to play with the values a bit but this is the basic idea

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have one question, even though it does create an array of 100 circle and a and b are producing the correct co-ordinates, it does not assign a and b as the x and y for the circle when drawing.

Comment: why do you say so?

Comment: it takes a and b as arguments `circles.push(new Circle(a, b));` , it stores those values at this.x and this.y `function Circle(x, y) { this.x = x; this.y = y;` , and then uses this.x and this.y to draw the circle `ellipse(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);`

Comment: it took time and effort for me to answer your question, i actually wrote all that code just for you, so please show a little bit of gratitude by at least telling me whats wrong with it

Comment: I'm really sorry, I am really really grateful. I wan't really sure what was going wrong as it wasn't spurting out an error. I have fixed it now and it was that I forgot to put this.x = x;. I'm really sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: its not a waste of my time if it helps you, its just that you werent answering. Do you have any other question? You might also consider marking my answer as accepted, it helps a lot. Have a nice day :)